# Isometry group of a quadratic form of signature $(1, 3)$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I'm reading a paper that has the following statement: The equation $m = n^2 - p_1^2 - p_2^2 - p_3^2$ expresses the area measured in triangles, as a quadratic form of signature $(1, 3)$. The isometry group of any such form is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^3)$ (here $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.)

I understand the first part of the statement. Could someone explain or point me to a reference about the second statement about Isometries of such a form?

Comment: What paper is it?

Comment: It's Shapes of Polyhedra by W. Thurston.

Comment: I understand the second part but not the first part! Hyperbolic space $\mathbb H^3$ is isomorphic to the upper sheet ($w>0$) of the hyperboloid $w^2-x^2-y^2-z^2=1$. Any isometry of $\mathbb H^3$ is an isometry of this quadratic form. The factor of $\mathbb Z_2$ encodes a reflection from the upper sheet to the lower sheet, which does not preserve $\mathbb H^3$ but does preserve the form.

Comment: @mr_e_man That explains it. Thanks!